# Python: write numpy array (int) to binary file without padding

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, io, binary

I have a binary file that was created in Fortran consisting of integer values as records. I want to read these into Python, edit them as lists and save them back to binary as np-arrays. For some reason, however, Python inserts an additional "0" after every record in the file. I guess this is what they call "padding", right? How do I suppress this?

Here's a standalone example:

```
import numpy as np

content = np.array(range(20))

# Write:
with open('D:/bin_test.dat', 'wb') as write_binary:
    write_binary.writelines(content)

# Read: 
with open('D:/bin_test.dat', 'rb') as read_binary:
    content = np.fromfile(read_binary, dtype=np.int16)

print content

Out: 
[ 0  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  4  0  5  0  6  0  7  0  8  0  9  0 10  0 11
0 12 0 13  0 14  0 15  0 16  0 17  0 18  0 19  0]
```

If I read the Fortran binary file via `np.fromfile` and save it back to binary directly, it works just fine. That's why I guess the problem occurs after conversion from list to numpy array.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have Python 2.7 (and that code won't work on Python 2.6), but on Python 3.6 your code does what you want if you change the datatype to `dtype=np.int32`.

Comment: Check `content.dtype`.  It looks like it is `np.int32`, which is generally the default integer type on Windows.  You are writing 32 bit integers, but then trying to read them back as 16 bit integers.  So every other value in the result is 0.

Comment: Sometimes it's as easy as that...yes, I have been trying to save HDD space by using 16bit integers in Fortran but did not realize numpy was creating int32 arrays by default. Well, ok, problem solved. Thank you!

Comment: OK, I'll add my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `content.dtype`. It looks like it is `np.int32`, which is generally the default integer type on Windows. You are writing 32 bit integers, but then trying to read them back as 16 bit integers. So every other value in the result is 0.